# Get QModelIndex from filepath and filename in QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qfilesystemmodel

I need to get the QModelIndex from a filepath and filename in a `QFileSystemModel`. I saw there is the `index` function which takes a `filepath` but I don't know what the column argument should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the [index()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#index-1) method of QFileSystemModel so that it can be accessed from QML:

```
class DisplayFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE QModelIndex index(const QString &path, int column = 0) const
    {
        return QFileSystemModel::index(path, column);    
    }
    ...
};
```

And then in QML you use it following form:

```
your_model.index(your_fullpath)
```